# Getting shogun ML library to work with python

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, shogun

I was trying to install shogun on Windows:

http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/installation.html

but evidently it requires python 2.5 to work. I tried with python 3 and it didn't work. But then python 2.5 no longer exists.

Does anybody know how to get it working with python without using python 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get very far trying with Python 3 (which is not fully compatible with Python 2.x).

Furthermore, the installation instructions say:

> "SHOGUN requires the standard linux
>   utils like bash, grep, test, sed, cut,
>   ldd, uname gcc g++ cat python"

sounds like you are out of luck on windows, unless you resort to [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: yeah i tried to use cygwin, but no luck nonetheless....in fact just trying to install shogun as a standalone didn't work in cygwin even though the instructions says it should work in cygwin

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two Python languages out there

- the original one, which is still being updated (currently at 2.7.2)
- the overhauled Python 3, which is breaking compatibility (currently at 3.1.4)

Many libraries have not switched to Python 3 yet, and might not for some time, so you're better off getting 2.6 or 2.7.

For Windows or Mac, I can recommend the [Enthought distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/edudownload.php) (free for academic use), which contains loads of goodies, including [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/), which you'll very probably need -- and installs hassle-free!